# Triangular Numbers Using Loops (Python)

Tags: python, loops

I'm currently working on a project that I'm working on, and I'm currently learning about looping. Here is the direction as follows...

> > > > Triangular numbers are numbers of objects that could be arranged in a triangle by     making rows, with one more object in each row than in the previous row. Write a function that given a number, n, will formulaically compute the nth Triangular number. Write another function that displays the Triangular numbers up to and including n.
> > > >
> > > > The formula states (n(n+1))/(2) or (n^(2)+n)/(2)

So pretty much I think I would need to formulate a function that whatever I enter for n to the equation I would get the answer. However, my question is I don't understand how loops is used in this scenario. I have done the following but I'm getting an error. I think it should very simple right?

```
n=int(input("Please Enter n:"))
y1=((n**2)+n)/(2)   
print (y1)
```

I think the code above answers the first question where it formulaically compute the nth Triangular number, given inputing n. However, I'm having a hard time to write a function for the second question where a function that displays the Triangular numbers up to and including n. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be something like this:

```
def all_triangle_numbers(n):
    for i in range(1, n + 1):   
        print("n = {0}, triangle = {1}".format(i, (i ** 2 + i)//2))

all_triangle_numbers(10)
```

Comment: Thanks you. Would you be able to help me for the second question? I'm having a hard time to write a function for the second question where a function that displays the Triangular numbers up to and including n.(Which I don't get quite what it means in the first place).

Comment: Thank you for your work. But, I'm having trouble because it asks up to and including n. How does that work?

Comment: I'm using an online complier, but it does work. I see from 1 to 10.

Comment: Glad I helped, enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting an error because of your `input()`, which should be `raw_input()`. However, if that is not the case, please state exactly what error you are getting.

Here is some working code:

```
def triangle(n):
    return ((n**2)+2)/2.0

n = int(raw_input('Please enter an integer: '))
print triangle(n)
```

Or, to print all the triangle numbers up to **and including *n***:

```
def all_triangles(n):
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        print ((i**2)+2)/2.0,

n = int(raw_input('Please enter an integer: '))
all_triangles(n)
```

Comment: I think the code actually works, but I will try out yours as well. Would you be able to help me for the second question? I'm having a hard time to write a function for the second question where a function that displays the Triangular numbers up to and including n.(Which I don't get quite what it means in the first place).

Comment: @python2learn, it sounds like this is the original first question that you had. This is the part that it is asking for either a `for loop` or a `while loop`. If this were me, I would make a `while loop` that states: `while (n>=0){#stuff; --n}`. Maybe this can implemented into the above answer?

Comment: Sorry I'm having trouble grasping on it. Would you be able to show me?